# Entity Framework Core 5 rounds decimal | .NET 5

Tags: sql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, decimal

App on .NET 5, EF-5. Before Db saved - screen.

[image: before]

In result I have in table

[image]

There is the second app on Core 3.1 EF-3.1 DB for both apps is common. Second app saved such I need. So the problem in EF. Result on screen. (numbers are other because the second app calculate data few minutes ago)

[image]

This column in the database is of type `DECIMAL (18, 4) NULL`, I tried to use `18,10` but in result I got only 10 zero after the point.

Two models in both apps are absolutely the same `public Nullable<decimal> MyValue { get; set; }`. I tried to do this way `decimal?` or with out `nullable`. The same result. Last chance was with it.

```
public DbContextConfiguration()
{
    var now = SqlProviderServices.Instance;
    SqlProviderServices.TruncateDecimalsToScale = false;
    this.SetProviderServices(SqlProviderServices.ProviderInvariantName, 
    SqlProviderServices.Instance);
}
```

But without result.

How I can to fix it?

Comment: The documentation says to use the `Precision` attribute on your property, like `[Precision(precision: 10, scale: 2)]`. Have you tried that?

Comment: no, I`m going to try it!

Comment: EF Core, like most if not all ORMs, will generate parameterized queries. `decimal` parameters require a precision and scale, so EF Core must specify *something*. In fact, the default scale in SQL Server is 0, so obviously EF Core specifies 2. If the database default was used, you'd see `0` in the database

Comment: @Blindy Thanks. It works! Create an answer and I will check it such right!